# ioS 7.1.2 CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807) on one device only

Tags: ios, ssl

We have an older "production" version of our app (never released but our production codebase for testing and demoing outside the dev codebase) that is used to demo.  We had the SSL certificate on the backend expire a week ago.  We updated the certificate, and all devices can again connect to our backend except one.  No matter what, that device gives

CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)
(which I believe is "invalid certificate chain")

Over and over again as the app tries to connect (over an NSURLConnection).  All other devices, including ones running the same iOS version, same app version, and on same network, have no issues and connect just fine.  Just this one device's app has issues.  The device is running iOS 7.1.2, and has been restarted, and the app has been deleted and reinstalled.  Also, the app has been tried both over a cell data connection and a WiFi connection.  Continues to give this error.  (This is the boss's phone and he gives the demos).  One of my test dev devices was upgraded to this same version of iOS and is running the same app.   It has no problem connecting.   My personal device, on the same network and app version, but a lower (7.0.x) version of iOS has no problem connecting.

I am not sure how to debug this.  I have not yet tried to rebuild the app (the codebase is 6 months old and I would have to get set up and checkout the old production branch) but was wondering if there are some simple tests or other things I can look at.

The backend server seems to be OK (only happens to this one device and some independent cert testers have connected and are fine with the certificate chain).

Comment: What is the URL of the server? Who is the intermediate issuer of the server cert; and who is the CA of the server cert? Also see [iOS 7: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012).

Comment: The URL is a private web services URL.  However, if I connect to it with Safari from OS X it validates and the path looks like this:  `AddTrust External CA Root -> COMODO RSA Certification Authority -> COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA --> *.MYDOMAIN.com`  where MYDOMAIN is a stand-in for the actual domain name (unreleased service).  Each of those levels checks out with OS X Safari as well (is marked as valid).  No other iOS device but this one has issues as well.

Comment: Revisit the question, and add the output of `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port>`. Once you get the output, Find/Replace the domain to `example.com`.